# how to resolve "WebSphere API classes are not available"?

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, datasource, websphere-liberty

I have Eclipse Mars with WAS Liberty installed with runtime trying to set up a datasource.  This is the error I'm getting:

"Could not initialize WebSphereDataSourceAdapter because WebSphere API classes are not available: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.ibm.websphere.rsadapter.WSDataSource"

I have this in my server.xml

```
<featureManager>
    <feature>javaee-7.0</feature>
    <feature>localConnector-1.0</feature>
    <feature>jdbc-4.1</feature>
    <feature>webProfile-7.0</feature>
</featureManager>
```

Other SOs have referenced a thin client jar file, but none exist in my wasruntime/lib directory nor inside any of those 346 jar files.  Any other ideas?

This is my spring declaration.

```
 <bean id="myDataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.WebSphereDataSourceAdapter">
   <property name="targetDataSource">
     <bean class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
       <property name="jndiName" value="jdbc/db2"/>
     </bean>
   </property>
 </bean>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The class `com.ibm.websphere.rsadapter.WSDataSource` doesn't exist in WebSphere Liberty.  It does exist in Traditional WebSphere, which is probably where the confusion is coming from.

If you have any control over specifying the class name, you could simply update it to the correct name.

If you don't have control over this, it sounds like a bug with the Spring Framework.  In the meantime you can work around this by specifying `javax.sql.DataSource` as a value for the `proxyInterface` property.

Change your spring declaration to the following:

```
<bean id="myDatasource" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
    <property name="jndiName" value="jdbc/db2"/>
    <property name="proxyInterface"  value="javax.sql.DataSource" />
</bean>
```

(Note: I also eliminated 1 layer of unnecessary nested config)

**Minor sidenote:** 
The feature list you posted has some extra stuff in it.  The `jdbc-4.1` and `webProfile-7.0` features are included in the overall `javaee-7.0` feature, so you should just change your feature manager to:

```
<featureManager>
    <feature>javaee-7.0</feature>
    <feature>localConnector-1.0</feature>
</featureManager>
```

Comment: This works, although I also needed to add the aopalliance-1.0.jar file.

Comment: interesting, what classes did you need to pull in the extra jar for?

Comment: It was org/aopalliance/aop/Advice.  I wasn't using maven to install spring, I just dumped the jars in there, that could be the reason.